# Which is correct regarding worry about

Tags: word-usage

You need not to worry about me stressing you out.

Or You need not to worry about me who stresses you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is different focus and meaning in terms of "not worrying":

*You need not to worry about me **stressing you out**.*

The focus in on the action of stressing.

while in

*You need not to worry **about me** who stresses you out.*

The focus is on me, the person doing the stressing.

Your pick, depending on the intent:-)